# How to return to the home screen with a terminal command?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Is there a terminal command to go to the home screen?

I need to do this **via ssh**, so I cannot just push the "home" button, I need to send a **command-line** action..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.HOME
```

More info about shell commands: [an archived version of the AndroidWiki page](http://web.archive.org/web/20130316123241/http://en.androidwiki.com/wiki/ADB_Shell_Command_Reference)

Answer (score 25):

Actually you can just push the "home" button

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME
```

[KEYCODE_HOME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME)

> Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.
>
> Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

Answer (score 8):

Consider taking at look at the following link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

`input keyevent KEYCODE_HOME`

Comment: FYI, `KEYCODE_HOME` is `3`.